# How can I show post category thumbnail?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to show the posts category image. When I use the `the_category_thumbnail()` function then I get a big error. Now, how can I show the category thumbnail image on my post?

Note: I successfully get just the WooCommerce product categories image with another function to use this query but I don't get any post categories image.

```php
$categories = get_categories([
    "orderby" => 'name',
    'number' => 4,
    'exclude' => 29,
]);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->name;
    echo $category->description;
    echo $category->the_category_thumbnail();
}
```

Comment: Firstly can you please tell me if you are using any plugin to add images to the category in the back-end?

Comment: No. I don't use any plugin in back end.

Comment: Okay, Can you see any option to add images to post categories?

Comment: No. I can't see.

Comment: Oh, There is no default WP functionality so for this, you have to add a custom snippet or try any plugin as there are many.

If you are familiar with the Advance Custom Fields plugin, you can assign images to Post Taxonomy.

Comment: Okey, I understand, and thanks to you.